# why is this shape showing for font awesome diamond?

Tags: html, font-awesome

I want a diamond shape from font awesome, but instead it has given me a weird shape.
I am not sure what I may be doing wrong.

[image]

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>

  <title>Home</title>
   </head>
    
    
    <body>

<i class="fas fa-diamond fa-2x"></i>

   </body>
   </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using Font Awesome 4, which doesn't have `.fas` class. So you'd need to use just the `.fa` icon or potentially look for an alternative with a newer version.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />

  <title>Home</title>
</head>


<body>

  <i class="fa fa-diamond fa-2x"></i>

</body>

</html>
```